# How to skip has_secure_password validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

In my app, only admins can create new User records. The user is emailed an activation link where they set their password.

I'd like to use the has_secure_passord method ([railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised)):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  ...
end
```

Works great, but it automatically validates presence of password digest...so when the admin creates the record the validations fail. I there a way to skip just the automatically added password_digest validation without skipping the others I've added?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I decided to do my own custom authentication. The following solution will validate passwords but only when they are being set. This allows admins to create users without adding a password.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include BCrypt

  attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation

  validates :password, length: (6..32), confirmation: true, if: :setting_password?

  def password=(password)
    @password = password
    self.password_hash = Password.create(password)
  end

  def authenticate(password)
    password.present? && password_hash.present? && Password.new(password_hash) == password
  end

private

  def setting_password?
    password || password_confirmation
  end

end
```

If someone posts an answer that allows me to still use the `has_secure_password` method, I'll accept it instead.

Comment: Hey just wanted to say thanks for this snippet worked perfectly for what I needed for social authentication

Comment: Inspirational, I'm using a slight variation of this right now to support multiple logins, allowing normal email/password login as well as password-less facebook authentications. bauce, say I!

Comment: You need to change your magic code as follow, otherwise, it will generate the password_digest even when the password is empty: `def password=(password) @password = password if password.present? self.password_digest = Password.create(password) end end`

Answer (score 33):

Since 4.X versions of rails, `has_secure_password` takes an option :validations. If you set it to `false`, it will not run validations.

The 3.X version of the gem does not support this parameter. However you can backport the activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb from [latest 4.0.XRC code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ef5d85709d346e55827e88f53430a2cbe1e5fb9e/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L51) which supports this argument.

So with that, your code will look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password :validations => false
  ...
end
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `:validations` in an optional way? I mean, if there is a password value, it should validate, otherwise, it skips.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to skip the validation, but it would be easy enough to write your own version of the method that allows you to pass an argument to determine whether or not to validate presence of the password_digest field.

Just extend `ActiveModel` the same way they do in the [SecurePassword module](https://github.com/lifo/docrails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb) (via `ActiveSupport::Concern`) and add your own secure password method.

i.e.

```
module ActiveModel
  module MySecurePassword
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods
      def my_has_secure_password(validate_password_digest=true)
        # you custom logic
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That could work. Feels kinda wrong though. I'm hoping I'll find something more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking off of Journeyer and Tybro's answers I wanted to see if you can add a private method that returns true or false to the validations hash. It worked and I used it for a different use case but in this context it would look something like this.

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password validations: !:setting_password

   #If setting_password is true then this will be the same as 
   validations: false
   ..... 
   private

   def setting_password?
    #Some logic that determines if a user is setting a password and resolves 
    to true or false
    password || password_confirmation
   end
   ...
  end
```

Comment: I've tried, but my code never runs the actual method. If I log anything in it, it never shows. 
`!:setting_password` always returns false, without the `!` always returns true.
Did you find a way?