# How can I sometimes require password and sometimes not with has_secure_password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app lets people register using a password OR with Facebook.

Even when I remove the password validations from my User model, I get `:password_digest => ["can't be blank"]` on the user model.

I use `has_secure_password`.

How can I make `password_digest` NOT required?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. [`has_secure_password`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password) automatically adds two validators to your model:

```
validates_confirmation_of :password
validates_presence_of     :password_digest
```

Instead, supply a dummy value for `password_digest` for users that don't have a password:

```
user.password = user.password_confirmation = ""
user.password_digest = "facebook-authorized account"
```

This is secure, as no password can possibly be hashed to match that digest.

Comment: Cool. Didn't have to manually set the password or password confirmation, but setting the digest did the trick.

Comment: Thanks @meagar, this is very helpful. In my case, I require a six digit password, so have done `user.password=user.password_confirmation='aaaaaa'` and `user.password_digest = 'special secret'`. In this case, do all facebook-authenticated-users have the same password of `special secret`? And I guess the 'aaaaaa' is ignored, as it is overwritten by the password_digest?

Comment: FYI, if using BCrypt, you'll need to make sure `password_digest != "facebook-authorized account"` when authenticating, otherwise you'll get an invalid hash error. Thanks @meagar.

Comment: @Sooie No, I don't think so. Can you explain further? I've never had an issue with hash errors; I'm pretty sure Rails will never attempt to "decrypt" the digested password; it only hashes the incoming password so that it can compare the two hashed values.

Comment: @meagar That's just what worked for me. When doing `user.authenticate(params[:password])` with the `password_digest` set to `No password set`, it throws a `BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash` error :/

Answer (score 7):

More recent commits have added an options hash to `has_secure_password` which allows skipping validations for the password_digest field. You use it like this:

```
 has_secure_password :validations => false
```

This is not present in the 3.2.13 version of rails unfortunately. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/16706045/1356792