# Make has_secure_password optional in rails 3.2.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to make `has_secure_password` optional in Rails 3.2.13? I know that there is the flag `validations:  false` but when I attempt to use it, it gives me an error that I'm using 1 argument where 0 is needed.

The purpose of this for me is to allow the creation of a user without a password set, so that the user can set the password themselves on a separate page.

Edit: I want it to validate all the other requirements except for the password, such as `validates :username, : presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 3 }` and other requirements.

Edit 2: See [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L58-60) and [here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/InstanceMethodsOnActivation.html) for more of what I am looking for. I am looking to write `has_secure_password validations: false` at the top of my model, but it gives me the error that I have an argument where none is needed. Is this feature not in Rails 3.2.13?

Comment: just make up a random password.  and then allow them to change it with first verifying the existing password?

Comment: I would like to avoid that so that they can set it themselves without having to type the first password.

Comment: Are you using it like `user.save(validations: false)`?

Comment: No, I'm passing it as `has_secure_password validations: false`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to skip has\_secure\_password validations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442466/how-to-skip-has-secure-password-validations) and many others including one I've previously answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917340/how-can-i-sometimes-require-password-and-sometimes-not-with-has-secure-password

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L58-60). It should accept `validations` as a parameter but it does not. Is this not in Ruby 3.2.13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching the source of `3.2.13` I realized that the release of `3.2.13` did not include the ability to use the `validations: false` flag. See [3.2.13](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-13/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb) source, compared to current [master branch's](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb) source.