# Skip Authenticate method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-authorization

I have a Sessions controller that requires authentication for creating a session using .authenticate method of **has_secure_password** defined in the User model, as per below:

Edit:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

# Relationships
 has_secure_password
 has_many :pedidos

 # Validations
 VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
 validates :nome, presence: true
 validates :empresa, presence: true
 validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },    
                format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
 validates :cpf, presence: true, length: { minimum: 11, maximum: 14 }
 validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }    

 def admin?
    self.admin
 end
end
```

SessionsController

```
def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:sessions][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:sessions][:password])
        flash[:success] = "Seja bem vindo(a), #{user.nome}!"            
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to user
    else
        flash.now[:danger] = 'Não foi possível realizar o login, '
        flash.now[:danger] += 'combinação usuário/senha inválido'
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Now I created an admin/Users controller that I would like to perform database operations without having to enter *password* and *password_confirmation* fields. In the current scenario I'm getting error messages saying "password and password_confirmation can't be blank"

How should I proceed? Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. You mention that your user method uses `has_secure_passwod` and say "as per below" but the example code you include doesn't contain your `User` model - just the controller. Can you please edit your question and add the code for the user model? that will help us pinpoint your bug.

Comment: Please Follow Below link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442466/how-to-skip-has-secure-password-validations## Heading ##

Comment: Please post code for your user model too

Comment: Thanks everyone, I've added the code of the User model, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If presumably your problem is that you'd like to be able to save new Users to your db without needing a password, one way might be to just add a dummy password for admins [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11917359/5657278)

Another might be to [skip validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#skipping-validations) when saving an admin to the db. (I haven't tried this with `has_secure_password` so I'm not positive that it'd work but worth a shot)

Comment: Thank you, .save(validate: false) will probably solve my problem in the Admin controller, although I'll have to use it very cautiously.