# Rails multiple conditional validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /^.+@.+\..+$/i 
  attr_accessible :active_list_id, :password, :password_confirmation, :email, :temp
  has_secure_password
  before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }
  if :temp.nil?
    before_validation :downcase_email
    validates_presence_of :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :on => :create
    validates_confirmation_of :password
    #something@something.something
    validates :email, :uniqueness => true, 
              :format => {:with => VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
  end
  after_create { make_list([email,"'s shopping list"].join('')) }

  has_many :shopping_lists
  has_many :transactions, :class_name => 'Order'

  HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES = {
    :password_digest => "Password"
  }
  ...
end
```

I try to create a model in my rails console by calling `User.create(:temp => true)` (which is a boolean and is defined in my migrations/schema). But it always rollsback the transaction. What am I doing wrong?

I also tried doing `:if => temp.nil?` and `if => "temp.nil?"`  and `:if => lambda { |user| user.temp.nil? }` for all 3 of my validations.

Comment: turns out has_secure_password auto validates :(

Answer (score 0):

create a method called temp_is_nil? and use that on the if condition

```
def temp_is_nil?
  temp.nil?
end
```

make sure that temp is an attribute of user.

```
before_validation :downcase_email, if: temp_is_nil?
validates_presence_of :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :on => :create, if: temp_is_nil?
validates_confirmation_of :password, if: temp_is_nil?
validates :email, :uniqueness => true, 
          :format => {:with => VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, if: temp_is_nil?
```

Comment: I figured it out. Turns out I can't skip has_secure_password validations. Here is a ~duplicate question with the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442466/how-to-skip-has-secure-password-validations