# Skip 'has_secure_password' validations based on a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, bcrypt

I have the following model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  # ...
end
```

I'm trying to skip validations from `has_secure_password` *helper* based on a condition.

So, after searching I found a way [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442466/how-to-skip-has-secure-password-validations#answer-16706045) to **ALWAYS** skip validations, however when I tried to adopt this solution in my case (as I said, I want to skip it based on a condition), as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password validations: :super_admin?

  private

  def super_admin?
    p "role #{role.inspect}"
    role == 'super_admin'
  end
end
```

... it doesn't skip the validation. It doesn't even call the `super_admin?` method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

for your case, the one that you need to skip is user.authenticate when you creating session for the user
below is sample of creating sesion with logical or if user.super_admin? equal true then it will pass and user can login

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    user = User.find_by_username(params[:session][:username])
    if user && (user.super_admin? || user.authenticate(params[:session][:password]))
      login user
      flash[:success] = "Successfully login"
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'sorry cannot login'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

end
```

in user.rb, remove private and check as follow

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def super_admin?
    p "role #{role.inspect}"
    role == 'super_admin'
  end
end
```